# Evaluate $\int_{0}^{1}{x\ln x dx}$.

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, improper-integrals, integration-by-parts

> Evaluate $\displaystyle\int_{0}^{1} x \ln x\, dx$.

I used integration by parts with $u=\ln x$ and $dv=x\,dx$.

Then I got this: $\displaystyle\frac{x^2 \ln x}{2}- \int_{0}^{1}\frac{x}{2}\,dx$.

But the problem is $\ln x$ is undefined when $x=0$. So how do I solve this?

Comment: Write your integral as a limit as the lower limit, $a$, goes to $0$.

Comment: You missed some factors $1/2$.. Anyway, take the integral from $\varepsilon$ to $1$, and then evaluate the limit

Comment: Do you remember the limit of $x\log(x)$ when $x\to 0$ ? Then $x^2\log(x)=x\times  (x\log(x))$

Answer (score 2):

First of all, you've miscalculated $v\,du.$ Also, since you're dealing with an improper integral, you'll need to find $$\lim_{a\searrow 0}\left[1^2\ln(1)-a^2\ln(a)-\int_a^1v\,du\right].$$ L'Hospitals rule should do the trick.

Comment: What's the purpose of $\searrow$? Is it an alternate notation for $a \to 0^+$? Never seen it.

Comment: @rubik: Yes, that's correct.

Comment: In densely-ordered sets (which may or may not have a notion of positivity), $a\searrow b$ indicates "$a$ approaches $b$ from above." I'm not sure where I first encountered the notation, but I prefer it over $a\to b^+$ for its intuitively suggestive visual.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, it's very interesting. The notation is indeed fairly intuitive, and I was able to grasp its meaning even though I had never encountered it.